# This site is not a scientific writting forum/publication support service?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I came across this question:

[The proper use of the terminology of forces and interactions in The Theory of Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333871/132157)

which I have a feeling should be off-topic, but I cannot really localize a specific help center guideline or meta answer that would pinpoint why, so I refrained from flagging it and/or commenting on it.

- Too localized?
- Not *really* about physics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users with the [close vote privilege](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) have the option of writing out a custom close reason for special cases like this (which I used when I put the question on hold); the close reason is posted as a comment to the question and counts as an ordinary close vote.
If you think a question should be closed but can't quite articulate why, you can also [flag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) the question as "should be closed" without worrying too much about the reason why; that puts the question in the [review queue](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review) and you can let the community decide whether the question is on-topic or not and why.

Comment: This is true, but I would not underestimate the benefit of pointing out the reason you think the question should be put on hold, even just by leaving a comment. Many times people will miss the reason you had in mind unless you prompt them. In other words, even when a question should be closed, it's often possible for someone to look at that question and simply not realize it.